# Laravel Update not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have table called admins and model called Admin.

When i try to update the records it fails every time with one field.

```
$admindetail = Admin::find($id);
$admindetail->fill(['is_delete'=>1])->save();
```

Above code is not updating record in DB. datatype for `is_delete` is tinyint.

If i update name field it works with the same code like

```
$admindetail = Admin::find($id);
$admindetail->fill(['name'=>'abc'])->save();
```

Can you help me why first code is not working.

Comment: have you is_delete in modal ?

Comment: no i have not use.

Comment: I defined it. It starts working.Thanks.

Comment: yes put an answer.i accept it

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Model use to interact with table so all attributes which you need to store in DB you should need to define in your model as your Admin model should look like

```
   <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Admin extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'is_delete'];
}
```

You missing `is_delete` from your Model code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing value as array, you could try the code below:

```
$admindetail = Admin::find($id);
if(!$admindetail)
{
  $admindetail->is_delete=1;
   $admindetail->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean type, no integer 1: `$adminDetail->fill(['is_delete' => true])->save();`

And you can use as property without `fill` method and you do not need accept `is_delete` in the `$fillable` array:

```
$adminDetail->is_delete = true;
$adminDetail->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check your fillable in your model like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'is_delete'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The update didn't work at all for me either. Then I found out that I called the transaction above and it didn't work because I returned without committing before returning.